# csupload Add-PersistentVMImage - clarification of <BlobStorageUTL> abd <YourImagesFolder>

Tags: azure

I am trying to upload a VHD using the syntax below:

csupload `Add-PersistentVMImage –Destination "<BlobStorageURL>/<YourImagesFolder>/<VHDName>" -Label <VHDName> -LiteralPath <PathToVHDFile> -OS Windows`

I am assuming the `<BlobStorageURL>` can be seen in the portal and is http://xx.blob.core.windows.net/ where "xx" has been replaced with the real subdomain.  BUT, please can someone explain where I can create or get `<YourImagesFolder>` from?

Kind Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

The xx is the name of your storage account, and the *.blob.core.windows.net URL points to the blob storage of that account (besides blob storage your account also contains queues and table storage).

Follow this guide to create a new storage account in the new Windows Azure Portal: [Create a Windows Azure Storage Account](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/#create-account)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I have just noticed that the syntax in my original post has been trunctated.  The original was this csupload Add-PersistenceVMImage -Destination "<BlobStorageURL>/<YourImagesFolder> ..  So, I presume <BlobStorageURL> should be set to http://xx.blob.core.windows.net but what about <YourImagesFolder>?

Comment: This is simply the name of a container in your storage account. You can't create a container in the portal, but I suggest you use a tool like CloudBerry Explorer (http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-microsoft-azure-explorer.aspx) to browse your storage account and create the container.